# How to view index page using ejs-templating rather than using express.static content in node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, npm, ejs

I can view my restaurant food menu generator with `HTML` with

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/index.html');});
```

with this `express static method`. But what if I wanted to view the `index page` with this `ejs-tempalting`. Here is my `main.js` code:

```
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var homeController = require("./Controllers/homeController.js");
var path = require("path");
const port = 3000,

express = require("express"),

app = express();
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.get('/function.js',function(req,res){ res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/javascript/function.js')); });
app.get('/main.css',function(req,res){ res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/css/main.css')); });
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
});
//should this view the index page?//
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index');
});

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.listen(port, () => {

 console.log(`The Express.js server has started and is listening
➥ on port number: ${port}`);
});
```

I have the `index.ejs`  in `views folder` but rumor says that you don't have to specify the path for the `ejs`. If I start the program, there are no errors but the page doesn't show either. So I'd appreciate if you can direct me to the right path, do I need `routes`? `Controllers`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to serve static files like `HTML` then What you are doing is correct. But if you want to serve `templating-engine` like `ejs` to the browser then you need to install dependency with below command

```
npm i ejs
```

and you need to import in your `main.js` file

```
const ejs = require('ejs');
```

Now, you need to setup `view engine`

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

in your `main.js` file. So, now your `main.js` file will look like

```
const express = require('express');
const ejs = require('ejs');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var homeController = require("./Controllers/homeController.js");
var path = require("path");

const app = express();
const port = 3000,

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//setup fir view engine
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

//this is used if you want to serve HTML file
//app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//should this view the index page?//
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
res.render('index');
});

app.listen(port, () => {
console.log(`The Express.js server has started and is listening
➥ on port number: ${port}`);
});
```

save `file` inside `views` folder with name `index.ejs`